# Dynamically adding data from server to auto complete TextField in iphone

Tags: ios, search, soap, autocomplete, textfield

I want to implement Google type searching in my iPhone application using Auto Complete Text field, like when user enters some characters it should give hints of related data coming from server using Soap web services.this service return whole data but i want it search as per character. I have searched lot. I am new one in iPhone development. Please any one help me and provide some useful links or tutorials. I got stuck in it.